# Bootstrap selectpicker onchange fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, smarty, bootstrap-select

The problem I'm having is that the change event on the [bootstrap select picker](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) is firing too much.

I have a select option using [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="ves">
    {foreach $ves as $vt}
        <option value="{$vt['v_id']}">{$vt['v_name']}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

The output from smarty looks like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="ves">
    <option value="1">Hello</option>
    <option value="2">World</option>
</select>
```

Then I call the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ves').on('change', function(){
       console.log('click');
       console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**Output on first select**:

> click
>   2

**Output on second select**:

> click
>   1
>   click
>   1

**Output on third select**:

> click
>   2
>   click
>   2
>   click
>   2

As you can see, it kind of accumulates, and I have no clue why. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you're binding the event each time there's a change. Are you sure that you're not?

Comment: If you can see a each in my posted source than I do, otherwise I don't. :) I posted all I'm using. That's the wired thing about it.

Comment: The posted source doesn't always reflect exactly what the code in the user's environment is actually doing. An each wouldn't do that.

Comment: I know. In my case it sadly does. It's just a .tpl file from smarty with html content and a select with a ID and a js file what is actually empty. Only the posted source... I just shorted the id's for better reading

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Because your example works fine. Needs to be something else. http://jsfiddle.net/wL5s6eLt/

Comment: Where is the JS located? In the template file?

Comment: @HugoSousa ill try, give me a min. #Popnoodles its a seperate file that gets included

Comment: [1 hour later] Seems like you can't reproduce the problem? :P

Comment: Sorry, forgot all about it because my daughter woke up. 1 year old. And I have solved it by overdoing all. Deleted all, built it new an now it works. May a miss placed bracket or some... Anyway, it works. Thanks :)